# Weird error uploading file with Spring Web Flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, multipartform-data

So, i have an upload file input in my web. This way:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="proyecto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" accept="image" name="foto">
<input type="submit" value="Next" name="_eventId_gotoPageTwo">
</form:form>
```

In the modelAttribute, I have a property called "foto":

```
public MultipartFile foto;
(...)
public MultipartFile getFoto() {
    return foto;
}
public void setFoto(MultipartFile foto) {

        System.out.println("Receiving image: "+foto.getOriginalFilename());

    this.foto = foto;
}
```

The CommonsMultipartResolver:

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

I have put a sysoyut there to check. The method is called, the name of the file is correct... but after this, a receive an Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException: A problem occurred restoring the flow execution with key 'e1s2'
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException: A problem occurred restoring the flow execution with key 'e1s2'
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.restoreExecution(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.java:82)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.restoreFlowExecution(AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.java:89)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.getFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:115)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:168)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)



org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotUnmarshalException: IOException thrown deserializing the flow execution stored in this snapshot -- this should not happen!
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.unmarshal(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:101)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.restoreExecution(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.java:80)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.restoreFlowExecution(AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.java:89)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.getFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:115)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:168)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)



java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Desarrollo\NuevoSTS\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.4.RELEASE\base-instance\work\Catalina\localhost\myproject\upload_f9d1d249_39f7_45f8_87ef_c28e7f61dbf3_00000006.tmp (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.readObject(DiskFileItem.java:684)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1184)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap.readObject(LocalAttributeMap.java:331)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowSessionImpl.readExternal(FlowSessionImpl.java:153)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
java.util.LinkedList.readObject(LinkedList.java:1136)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.readExternal(FlowExecutionImpl.java:304)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.deserialize(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:194)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.unmarshal(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:99)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.restoreExecution(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.java:80)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.restoreFlowExecution(AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.java:89)
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.getFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:115)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:168)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Its strange, because it looks like Spring is losing the file AFTER binding it, because the sysout shows perfectly.

Any help? Thank you.

UPDATE:

The view-state:

```
<view-state id="inicio" view="inicio" model="proyecto">
<binder>
            <binding property="titulo"/>
            <binding property="descripcion"/>
            <binding property="ciudad"/>
            <binding property="foto"/>
        </binder>

    <transition on="gotoPageTwo" to="flow2"></transition>
 </view-state>
```

Comment: Did you declare CommonsMultipartResolver in servlet context xml?

Comment: Yes, forgot to specify it in the code above. Updating.

Comment: Questions: 1)In your flow for this view, you have not disabled binding right? 2) Did you specify flow execution key in jsp as: <input type="hidden" id="_flowExecutionKey" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="<c:out value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>"/>    ?

Comment: 1) I am binding specifically all the properties in the form. If I comment out the <binding property="foto"> no error is shown.
2)I have <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}">.

Comment: Post your view state from flow - want to see transitions and actions for it.

Comment: Updated the question to show it.

Comment: Nice workaround, you can do the same/check in validator for the view.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a workaround... not exactly a solution, but at least I can get the image. In the model class, added new byte[] property, with getters and setters. In the setFoto() method (The one called by Spring):

```
public void setFoto(MultipartFile foto) {

        System.out.println("Receiving image: "+foto.getOriginalFilename());
    try {
        fotobytes=foto.getBytes();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.foto = null;
    foto=null;
}
```

This way, I get the bytes in the image, and I can store it in Database if needed, or displayed directly from bytes. The important thing, imo, is setting foto null. This way, Springs doesnt needs to look for the file that the Exception seems to show Spring has lost...

As I said, not exactly a solution, so I will not give the question as answered, but at least I have my image.